# mvn's classpath doesn't contain the project's own jar

Tags: maven

I'm trying to start up an snapshot instance from Jenkins for a maven projectA. In order to get the correct classpath for the instance, the following command is executed under the same dir of projectA's pom.xml

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable=./instance_start.sh -Dexec.args='%classpath'
```

Where the script takes advantage of getting class path from '%classpath' var from mvn and append it to a instance.properties file and then starts the instance.

My problem is the %classpath only contains projectA's dependencies, but doesn't have projectA's own snapshot jar, which makes it not able to start up, I need to manually add the /path/to/projectA/verion-SNAPSHOT.jar to the classpath. I think I'm missing something here, is it possible to get the classpath for all dependency jars PLUS projectA's jar?

Comment: who sets that variable ? and does it have path to `target/classes` for the same proejct

Comment: it doesn't - actually this is the root cause of the issue, for my jenkins job, I didn't do mvn install for the job, therefore there's only dependency jars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get this resolved, in my Jenkins job, I didn't build the project, was just pulling the pom.xml and execute the mvn exec:exec on top of it, this makes maven fail to add target/classes that're generated by 'mvn install' the job.
Problem solved after I change the jenkins job to a standard maven build job that do mvn install first and mvn exec:exec later.